# Git stuck on writing objects, no large files

Tags: git

So yesterday I `CNTRL-C` and stopped a `git push` in the middle of it which I initially thought was causing this writing objects problem because every time I tried to re-push it would stay on the percentage I left off at.

I've done a

```
git revert <commit_hash>
git add .
git commit -m "blah"
git push -u origin x
```

again and it is still stuck. There are no large files because I just changed a small html line and have never seen this problem before.

It just keeps adding lines of `Writing objects...` and fills up the whole terminal window.

[image: git stuck]

Can someone please help me?

Comment: It doesn't look stuck, just slow. Consider using git-lfs for large files, or not committing them at all?

Comment: Nothing happens though, the percentage doesn't change and the `MiB` just keeps increasing, I could leave it an hour and it just stays on the same percentage. I'm working on a project that does not have large files, like I mentioned I have done over 60 commits and this time, just changed one line so it should not be having this problem. It normally takes a few seconds to `git push`

Comment: If the MB go up, surely it is working?

Comment: It's not though because it will stay for hours on that screen, something is clearly not right as I mentioned, there are no large files and no need for the increasing mib.

Comment: Can you try making a fresh clone in another folder? Also consider changing internet connection?

Comment: @evolutionxbox thank you for your help, I managed to fix it with the answer I posted below, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a `git reset --hard origin/master` and lost the changes (I luckily changed one line only) then re-did the change, and

```
git add .
git commit 
git push
```

and it pushed the changes in seconds like normal.

Comment: Thankfully the changes are still recoverable. Check the reflog to find the commit git "lost".

Comment: Do not do git reset --hard unless you are prepared to lost all your work!